# Move repeating background to the left some before repeat

Tags: css

The repeating background image, the landscape in the link below, has a white space after the first image ends and the repetition begins.

Since I don't think there is a way to crop an .svg without rasterising it into a bitmap, how can I have the background move the left some before repetition to cover the white-space?

Here is the link to where this is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/search/new.html

Comment: Hm, that's tricky. My first question would be, is there any advantage in having this background image as a .svg file? I don't see an obvious advantage. The second thing I'd look at is perhaps editing the original to remove that space at the right, though I admit I'm not experienced with .svg files.

Comment: @ralph.m I can edit the original .svg file, but I don't know how to crop the ends off an .svg image. I don think they can be opened in Photoshop.

Comment: Open the image in a browser window by itself and take a screen capture.Then paste into Photoshop.

Comment: @KevinBoucher but then it wouldn't be an .svg. I know how to make it a  raster-image then crop it. The question is how to crop it while it is still a vector.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with editing. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: @CodyGuldner Ah, I see. Okay, i'm sorry. I'll post with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to crop the image using CSS, having a look at your site though, I was able to get it to look pretty good by adding a pseudo-element with the same background after the `#input` element, and then setting its `background-position` to `2px` to make it move to the right by 2 pixels. This renders another copy of you background image behind the `#input` element, moving its `background-image` to the right by `2px` effectively fills up the `2px` gap which is left by the `#input` elements `background-image`.

```
#input:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(dawn.svg) top left repeat-x;
  background-position: 2px;
  margin-top: -17px;
}
```

**Edit:**

Doing this with setting the background on the header element instead of a pseudo-element, and fixing the logo width:

```
#header
{
  background: url("dawn.svg") repeat-x 302px; /* 302 is logo-width (300px) + 2px */
}

#logo {
  background: url("logo.svg") no-repeat center center / 100% auto #FFFFFF; 
  /* Make the background-color white. */
  width: 300px;
}
```

Or without a fixed-width logo and rendering an extra `div` instead of a pseudo-element:

**HTML**

```
<section id="input">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="searchInput">
</section>
<div id="backgroundfix"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#backgroundfix {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(dawn.svg) top left repeat-x;
  background-position: 2px;
  margin-top: -17px;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. clever solution. Except it only works when pseudo elements are supported. How can I do it with one of the elements that contain #input such as the header. Can I apply this giving it the same background, but shifting it 2 to the right technique to the header?

Comment: also, why the margin-top: -17px ?

Comment: Yes, pseudo-elements are supported IE8 and up, and [everywhere else](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent). The `margin-top` is because the element gets rendered after `#input` and gets pushed down by `#input`'s content because of its relative positioning.

Comment: ah, okay. Can you tell me how to apply this technique to the header element, the physical container of #input, so that it can work in less than IE8?

Comment: Yes, that is what I originally tried, but your logo being of a variable width was messing things up for me. I think it would work if you had the logo at a fixed width. Or you could just render a `div` directly after `#input` and add the above CSS class to it, instead of using CSS to create the pseudo-element. That would work in IE7.

Comment: Could you update your answer with any of the html / markup changes I need to make and any of the css changes I need to make to get it working like that. Even if it means fixing the width of the logo.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'll check it out tomorrow and select it as the answer.

Comment: wait, why the scroll in the updated shorthand background property? What is that a value for a why did you use it?

Comment: My Google Chrome Devtools just add it. And I copy/paste from there. You can just get rid of it as it is the default value for `background-attachment`.

Comment: I had to add relative positioning to position the backgroundFix element behind the #input, but there is still some white-space. What am I doing wrong? Here is a link to it: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/search/new.html

Comment: The white space is your input text box, which is now behind your `#backgroundFix div`, set `z-index: -1;` on `#backgroundFix`. That will put it behind the `#input1 div`, and thereby also behind the text box. That should be all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't just use a .png instead, a CSS3 alternative would be a workaround like this:

```
#input {
  background:
  url(dawn.svg) 1512px 0 no-repeat,
  url(dawn.svg) 756px 0 no-repeat, 
  url(dawn.svg) 0 0 no-repeat
}
```

Of course, you are left with the problem of IE8 and under, if this matters to you—though personally, I'd give them just the one repeated background with the gap.

Comment: Ah, multiple backgrounds. Good technique, but supporting IE8 and under as much as I can is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, IE8 doesn't really support SVG anyway (at least not without a lot of assistance), so if compatibility is a big issue, I'd rethink the use of .svg altogether. Seems like more of a headache that it's worth here.

Comment: Also, your layout is pretty messed up in IE8 already, so make sure to check regularly as you go, so that you can address issues as they arise.

Comment: really? I don't think I'm using anything that would cause it to break in IE8. Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: This is what I see in IE8 (warning, may shock you): [link](http://pageaffairs.com/sp/so-16270338.png)